Websites down - Status: "MariaDB server is down"
I am running an Ubuntu webserver on a VPS with several websites hosted. I am using ISPConfig3 to host them.
Today they are all not working with an error;

Error establishing a database connection

I am also unable to log in to the ISPConfig UI as it shows;

This page isn't working at the moment - HTTP ERROR 500

So, I checked whether MariaDb was running using systemctl status mariadb and the results are as follows;
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.39 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d
             └─limits.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-11-06 10:48:57 GMT; 3min 23s ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 323 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 363 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 385 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, statu>
    Process: 573 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 573 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Nov 06 09:36:23 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 06 09:36:23 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 06 09:36:23 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.39 database server.
Nov 06 10:48:53 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.39 database server...
Nov 06 10:48:57 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 06 10:48:57 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 06 10:48:57 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.39 database server.
Oct 31 19:53:10 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.39 database server...
Oct 31 19:53:20 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.3.39 database server.
Oct 31 19:53:20 server.companydomain.co.uk /etc/mysql/debian-start[1343]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
Oct 31 19:53:20 server.companydomain.co.uk /etc/mysql/debian-start[1350]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Oct 31 19:53:20 server.companydomain.co.uk /etc/mysql/debian-start[1350]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
Oct 31 19:53:20 server.companydomain.co.uk /etc/mysql/debian-start[1350]: This installation of MariaDB is already upgraded to 10.3.39-MariaDB.
Oct 31 19:53:20 server.companydomain.co.uk /etc/mysql/debian-start[1350]: There is no need to run mysql_upgrade again for 10.3.39-MariaDB.
Oct 31 19:53:20 server.companydomain.co.uk /etc/mysql/debian-start[1350]: You can use --force if you still want to run mysql_upgrade
Oct 31 19:53:20 server.companydomain.co.uk /etc/mysql/debian-start[1365]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
Oct 31 19:53:20 server.companydomain.co.uk /etc/mysql/debian-start[1369]: Triggering myisam-recover for all MyISAM tables and aria-recover for all Aria tables
Nov 06 03:25:27 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Nov 06 03:40:27 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Skipping SIGKILL.
Nov 06 03:40:27 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Nov 06 03:40:32 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Nov 06 03:40:32 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.3.39 database server.
Nov 06 03:40:32 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.39 database server...
Nov 06 03:40:35 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 06 03:40:35 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 06 03:40:35 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.39 database server.
Nov 06 09:08:45 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 06 09:08:45 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 06 09:08:45 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.39 database server.

I have also tried restarting the server and also the Mariadb service;
sudo service mariadb restart

But get the following error;

Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

systemctl status mariadb.service

Results;
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.39 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d
             └─limits.conf
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-11-06 10:53:39 GMT; 1h 24min ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 1666 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1667 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 1668 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, stat>
    Process: 1716 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1716 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"

Nov 06 10:53:37 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.39 database server...
Nov 06 10:53:39 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 06 10:53:39 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 06 10:53:39 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.39 database server.
Nov 06 03:25:27 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Nov 06 03:40:27 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: State 'stop-sigterm' timed out. Skipping SIGKILL.
Nov 06 03:40:27 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Nov 06 03:40:32 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Nov 06 03:40:32 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: Stopped MariaDB 10.3.39 database server.
Nov 06 03:40:32 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.39 database server...
Nov 06 03:40:35 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 06 03:40:35 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 06 03:40:35 server.companydomain.co.uk systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.3.39 database server.

When I execute;
journalctl -xe

Results;
Nov 06 12:16:58 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/cleanup[4713]: warning: proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_outgoing_bcc.cf lookup error for "root@server.companydomain.co.uk"
Nov 06 12:16:58 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/cleanup[4713]: warning: 4E31455918: sender_bcc_maps map lookup problem -- message not accepted, try again later
Nov 06 12:16:58 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/pickup[1298]: warning: maildrop/A0D7E555CA: error writing 4E31455918: queue file write error
Nov 06 12:16:58 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[7235]: Failed password for invalid user apa from 162.215.216.231 port 36716 ssh2
Nov 06 12:17:00 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[7235]: Connection closed by invalid user apa 162.215.216.231 port 36716 [preauth]
Nov 06 12:17:01 server.companydomain.co.uk CRON[7238]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 06 12:17:01 server.companydomain.co.uk CRON[7239]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 06 12:17:01 server.companydomain.co.uk CRON[7240]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/ispconfig/server/server.sh 2>&1 | while read line; do echo `/bin/date` "$line" >> /var/log/ispconfig/cron.log; done)
Nov 06 12:17:01 server.companydomain.co.uk CRON[7241]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/ispconfig/server/cron.sh 2>&1 | while read line; do echo `/bin/date` "$line" >> /var/log/ispconfig/cron.log; done)
Nov 06 12:17:02 server.companydomain.co.uk dovecot[510]: auth-worker(7237): Error: mysql(localhost): Connect failed to database (dbispconfig): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) - waiting >
Oct 31 21:20:43 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[6579]: Invalid user updata2 from 92.118.39.100 port 51230
Oct 31 21:20:43 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[6579]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Oct 31 21:20:43 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[6579]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=92.118.39.100
Nov 06 12:17:11 server.companydomain.co.uk CRON[7238]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 31 21:20:45 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[6579]: Failed password for invalid user updata2 from 92.118.39.100 port 51230 ssh2
Oct 31 21:20:46 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[6579]: Connection closed by invalid user updata2 92.118.39.100 port 51230 [preauth]
Nov 06 12:17:14 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/smtpd[6444]: connect from unknown[94.141.120.244]
Nov 06 12:17:14 server.companydomain.co.uk dovecot[510]: auth: Error: auth worker: Aborted PASSV request for oracle: Worker process died unexpectedly
Nov 06 12:17:14 server.companydomain.co.uk dovecot[510]: auth-worker(7237): Fatal: master: service(auth-worker): child 7237 killed with signal 11 (core dumps disabled - https://dovecot.org/bugreport.html#coredumps)
Nov 06 12:17:14 server.companydomain.co.uk dovecot[510]: auth-worker(7267): Error: mysql(localhost): Connect failed to database (dbispconfig): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) - waiting >
Oct 31 21:20:48 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/smtpd[2964]: connect from unknown[194.169.175.10]
Nov 06 12:17:15 server.companydomain.co.uk dovecot[510]: auth-worker(7267): Error: mysql(localhost): Connect failed to database (dbispconfig): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) - waiting >
Nov 06 12:17:16 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/smtpd[6444]: warning: unknown[94.141.120.244]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Nov 06 12:17:16 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/smtpd[6444]: disconnect from unknown[94.141.120.244] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 quit=1 commands=2/3
Nov 06 12:17:18 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/submission/smtpd[5346]: connect from unknown[104.43.200.55]
Nov 06 12:17:18 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/submission/smtpd[5346]: disconnect from unknown[104.43.200.55] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 quit=1 commands=2/3
Nov 06 12:17:19 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[7268]: Invalid user yuguangyi from 92.118.39.81 port 52154
Nov 06 12:17:19 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[7268]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Nov 06 12:17:19 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[7268]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=92.118.39.81
Oct 31 21:20:52 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/smtpd[2964]: warning: unknown[194.169.175.10]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Oct 31 21:20:52 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/smtpd[2964]: disconnect from unknown[194.169.175.10] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
Nov 06 12:17:20 server.companydomain.co.uk dovecot[510]: auth-worker(7267): Error: mysql(localhost): Connect failed to database (dbispconfig): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) - waiting >
Nov 06 12:17:21 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[7268]: Failed password for invalid user yuguangyi from 92.118.39.81 port 52154 ssh2
Nov 06 12:17:21 server.companydomain.co.uk CRON[7239]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 06 12:17:22 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[7275]: Invalid user lol from 138.68.155.239 port 59800
Nov 06 12:17:22 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[7275]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Nov 06 12:17:22 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[7275]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=138.68.155.239
Nov 06 12:17:22 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[7268]: Connection closed by invalid user yuguangyi 92.118.39.81 port 52154 [preauth]
Nov 06 12:17:24 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/smtpd[6440]: connect from unknown[194.169.175.10]
Nov 06 12:17:24 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[7275]: Failed password for invalid user lol from 138.68.155.239 port 59800 ssh2
Nov 06 12:17:26 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[7275]: Connection closed by invalid user lol 138.68.155.239 port 59800 [preauth]
Oct 31 21:21:01 server.companydomain.co.uk CRON[6583]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 31 21:21:01 server.companydomain.co.uk CRON[6582]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct 31 21:21:01 server.companydomain.co.uk CRON[6584]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/ispconfig/server/cron.sh 2>&1 | while read line; do echo `/bin/date` "$line" >> /var/log/ispconfig/cron.log; done)
Oct 31 21:21:01 server.companydomain.co.uk CRON[6585]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/ispconfig/server/server.sh 2>&1 | while read line; do echo `/bin/date` "$line" >> /var/log/ispconfig/cron.log; done)
Oct 31 21:21:01 server.companydomain.co.uk CRON[6582]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct 31 21:21:01 server.companydomain.co.uk CRON[6583]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 06 12:17:29 server.companydomain.co.uk dovecot[510]: auth-worker(7267): Fatal: master: service(auth-worker): child 7267 killed with signal 11 (core dumps disabled - https://dovecot.org/bugreport.html#coredumps)
Nov 06 12:17:29 server.companydomain.co.uk dovecot[510]: auth: Error: auth worker: Aborted PASSV request for operationslead@co.uk: Worker process died unexpectedly
Nov 06 12:17:29 server.companydomain.co.uk dovecot[510]: auth-worker(7277): Error: mysql(localhost): Connect failed to database (dbispconfig): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) - waiting >
Nov 06 12:17:30 server.companydomain.co.uk dovecot[510]: auth-worker(7277): Error: mysql(localhost): Connect failed to database (dbispconfig): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) - waiting >
Nov 06 12:17:31 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/smtpd[6440]: warning: unknown[194.169.175.10]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Nov 06 12:17:32 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/smtpd[6440]: disconnect from unknown[194.169.175.10] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
Nov 06 12:17:35 server.companydomain.co.uk dovecot[510]: auth-worker(7277): Error: mysql(localhost): Connect failed to database (dbispconfig): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) - waiting >
Oct 31 21:21:17 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/smtpd[4976]: connect from unknown[194.169.175.10]
Oct 31 21:21:21 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/smtpd[4976]: warning: unknown[194.169.175.10]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Oct 31 21:21:21 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/smtpd[4976]: disconnect from unknown[194.169.175.10] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
Oct 31 21:21:24 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[6601]: Invalid user antao from 92.118.39.84 port 58010
Oct 31 21:21:24 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[6601]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Oct 31 21:21:24 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[6601]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=92.118.39.84
Oct 31 21:21:26 server.companydomain.co.uk sshd[6601]: Failed password for invalid user antao from 92.118.39.84 port 58010 ssh2
Nov 06 12:17:54 server.companydomain.co.uk postfix/smtpd[6444]: connect from unknown[194.169.175.10]

I don't relish having to rebuild the VPS and re-install about 10 websites, so would appreciate any help at all. As you can tell, I am out of my depth here... so any hand-holding would be appreciated.
Many thanks
Edit - as requested by @Matigo...
I was short on space, so deleted 40Gb of unwanted data - so the size of the disk is 250Gb and it currently has 70Gb of free space.
The last few entries in /var/log/mysql is;
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.3.39-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 source revision ca001cf2048f0152689e1895e2dc15486dd0b1af as process 554
Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x3ee77)
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.39 started; log sequence number 805887102760; transaction id 63756466
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [ERROR] Aria engine is not enabled or did not start. The Aria engine must be enabled to continue as mysqld was configured with --with-aria-tmp-tables
2024-11-06  9:08:43 0 [ERROR] Aborting

I see the Aria errors, but have no understanding of what this is. I see the instructions to attempt to fix the Aria tables/files, but am unsure where they are located.
I have tried aria_chk -r from SSH and it brings up a help file showing Global Options - but I dont see any way of running this on ALL tables... or how to get a list of tables (if you have to specify each individually).

The error log in /var/log/mysql should have a more specific set of error messages. Could you [edit] your question to include the more recent messages from there? It would also be a good idea to confirm you still have enough storage space remaining on the server. If you’re at 90% or more, then you will need to start freeing space.

There are some pretty clear error messages in your /var/log/mysql. Please edit your question to explain what you did about those Aria errors.

Thanks for the pointers @matigo & @user535733... I have managed to recover the server by doing the following...
I found that the MariaDB tables are stored in /var/lib/mysql/ - so I made a backup of this folder and then performed the following actions...
To repair all the tables I performed the following:
aria_chk -r /var/lib/mysql/**/*

After this I deleted all the log files;
rm /var/lib/mysql/aria_log.*

After this I rebooted the server and the websites are working again.
Hopefully this may help someone else searching for a solution to a similar problem.
